# Flask instanciation app = Flask()

Tags: python, flask, init

I intentionally removed **name** in app = Flask(**name**)  and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "routes.py", line 4, in <module>
        app = Flask() 
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

this is my code from [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework/) and here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask() 

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My question is: Where is this **init** method that takes at least 2 arguments?

Comment: If you want to see Flask's actual code you can go to /venv/lib/python.27/site-packages/flask 

All of the things you install with pip are here, if you used virtualenv, which you should be doing ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you understand the concept of class and objects, then `__init__` is the constructor which initializes an instance of the class. In this case, the class is Flask and when you do the following, you are initializing the instance of a Flask object:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Now your question, "Where is this init method that takes at least 2 arguments?"

That can be explained as per the definition below that defines the constructor in the code.

```
def __init__(self, import_name, static_path=None, static_url_path=None,
                 static_folder='static', template_folder='templates',
                 instance_path=None, instance_relative_config=False):
```

If you see above, `self` and `import name` is the required parameter and rest are all defaulted or not required. The `self` is needed by Python even though you can name it anything else. read this blog by creator of python himself for why http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Answer (score 7):

`__init__` is akin to a constructor in python - its the function which gets called when you create a new instance of an object, in this case the `Flask` application object.

App objects need an `import_name`, which is the first argument you pass to the `Flask` constructor. You can read more about that [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-object) (see "About the First Parameter")

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: Where is this init method that takes at least 2
>   arguments?

It's right here:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L401

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the Flask app a name:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

`__name__` will be the name of the current module, but you can call it anything you want in principle...

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: `__init__` is called as a consequence of calling `Flask()`. Your original call is meant to *initiate* an instance of the class `Flask`, and `__init__` is the function that does the setup.

To solve your immediate problem though: **You only need to pass one argument. The Error message is misleading.**

It's not *incorrect* but it's talking about a function that's not the one you *think* you called. @codegeek 's example shows you what the "first" argument is. It's `self`. But that's passed from inside the Class when `class.__init__` is called as a *consequence* of calling `Flask()`. You don't see `self` being used, except for implicitly -- it's the (1 given) argument in your traceback, when you *thought* you were passing *zero* arguments.

Importantly, this isn't unique to this case -- you'll see the same thing in very simple examples like:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, one):
        self.one = one
ex = Example()
```

This will produce:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Meaning, `Example()` calls `__init__` which wants 'self' and 'one', and it only got 'self'.

(From the question though, I strongly recommend you read something like this http://pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-python-classes/ or another intro to python classes. Classes are a fundamental element of the language, and initializing them is a basic part of their functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question, the **__init__** method is the default constructor for the Flask() class here. It simply resides in the Flask class that you just imported from the statement

```
from flask import Flask
```

So, the moment you say

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

All it does is just instantiates an object of this Flask class. And since you did not pass the **__name__** parameter, hence it throws the error.

And you can find the the **__init__** method [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L315)